# Ajax submitHandler not executing

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I want php file to execute through ajax but it just posts like normal through form and loads a new page. I have checked heaps of code on here and still it always does not execute through submitHandler and ajax. I have checked host provider and ajax is supported and i have done other tests with jquery and it works fine. Just can't get this to work how it should. the php file executes perferectly and inserts data into the database so I am guessing I am missing something with the validate code.

```js
$("#emailForm").validate({

   submitHandler: function(form) {
//       event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       url: $(form).attr("action"),
       type: $(form).attr("method"),
       data: $(form).serialize(),
       success: function(response) {
         document.getElementById("fee").style.display = "block";
       }
     });
     return false;
   }
 });
```

```css
#fee {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="screen">

    <div class="contents">
      <form class="cmxform" id="emailForm" method="post" action="process.php">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Sign up now and secure your username!
          </legend>
          <p>
            <label for="cname">Username (required, at least 5 characters)
            </label>
            <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="5" type="text" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="cpassword">Password (required, at least 8 characters)
            </label>
            <input id="cpassword" name="password" minlength="8" type="password" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="cemail">Email (required)
            </label>
            <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <div id='fee'>Signup Complete!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure your javascript is executing at all? 2) Have you checked the console for errors? 3) I don't see where you are preventing the form from submitting (`e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: ohhh! I have to prevent default? I will google it :)

Comment: @JasonP i updated my javascript but it still loads in new page, I am using preventDefault correctly?

Comment: @JasonP I realize adding event.preventDefault(); is not required as return false; prevents the default submit. But it still loads in a new page. I have no console errors and the .validate is working correctly so the javascript must be executing.

Comment: In your edit, `event` doesn't exist. You need it passed as a parameter to the submithandler function. Where are you doing return false? In the form html? If that is there, the form should not submit in a normal full page post.

Comment: @JasonP I return false; in the javascript as stated here [link](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/650)

Comment: Oh i didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with, because using form object I am not sure its is Javascript DOM object ot jQuery object so I have convert object into jQuery object and used attr() method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#emailForm").validate({

   submitHandler: function(form) {
     $.ajax({
       url: $(form).attr("action"),
       type: $(form).attr("method"),
       data: $(form).serialize(),
       success: function(response) {
         document.getElementById("fee").style.display = "block";
       }
     });
     return false;
   }
 });
 });
```

Comment: this also loads the php in a new page, thanks though!

Comment: I have. @JasonP makes sense that i have not prevented the default, but i am not 100% how this is done because it is not in any of the examples.

Comment: Okay, I undertsnad that adding return false; prevents the default form from submitting. But it still is.

Comment: added $(document).ready(function () { }); to answer to make it correct.